# Does a UK Citizen with a foreign passport need a Visa to enter the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, dual-nationality

I am a UK citizen and I live in Colombia. My daughter is due to be born soon. When she is born I will register her birth at the UK Embassy here in Colombia so she will have a UK birth certificate and will be a UK Citizen. Due to time constraints, in the first instance it's easier and quicker for us to get her a Colombian Passport (later we'll get her UK one). Will she need a UK visa to visit the UK if she is travelling on her Colombian passport?

Comment: I would check with the consulate AND the airline. If the consulate says it is allowed (which I doubt), the airline might still deny you boarding. If you are denied entry it is the airlines responsibility to bring you back. In the end they only check Visa and passports.

Comment: [Registering birth abroad](https://www.gov.uk/register-a-birth) is different from [registering British citizenship](https://www.gov.uk/register-british-citizen/children-born-outside-uk). You may wish to defer registering citizenship until she has lived in the UK at least three years, otherwise [she will be considered a British citizen _by descent_](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/261503/bn4.pdf) and unable to automatically pass on citizenship.

Answer (score 7):

You may need to clarify this with the consulate in Colombia but from what I can see online your daughter will be a [Family Visitor](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/visiting/family/) traveling as a Colombian citizen, which means that she will need a visa to enter.

So I would suggest that you apply not only for the British Birth certificate but also for a travel document for her to enter the UK as well.